# Draggable moved when container has border

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a horizontal bar that is draggable vertically, and the container of the bar has a `border-top`. When I drag the bar, the bar shifts up (on mouse move). Anyone knows why this is happening and how I can fix this other than removing the border? Thanks a lot!

### CSS

```
body {
     border-top: 5px;
}
```

### jQuery

```
$("#horz").draggable({
     axis: "y"
});
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/3vkhN/6/

Comment: change `position:absolute` to `position:relative`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to do this

```
#guidelines {
    position: relative;
}
```

To make your `#horz` element positioned based on its parent instead of the body.

You may want to consider whether you also need to use a boundary with draggable, it depends on what you are trying to do and whether the `#horz` even needs to be absolutely positioned.